# Azure Media Player Silverlight fallback not working

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, azure, azure-media-services

I have used the azure media player with my project, it will play multiple adaptive bit rate streamed videos in an asp.net page, the best part is, it is working superb in html5 and flash but it will get stuck at spinner image in silverlight fallback.

Below is the code I have used.

I have also tried to get errors but it is not hitting the event listener code added for errors, but the play and pause events are working fine where flash and html5 is used, but silverlight fallback is not working at all.

```
<link href="https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
<div class="marginBlock">
<h3>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server"><%=Title.ToString()%></asp:Label>
</h3>
<video id="<%=mediaPlayerID %>" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered">
    <p class="amp-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML 5 video.
    </p>
</video>
</div>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server"><%=Description.ToString()%>
    </asp:Label>
</p>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var playOptions = {
        "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
        techOrder: ['azureHtml5JS', 'flashSS', 'silverlightSS', 'html5'],
        autoplay: false,
        controls: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: '400',
        logo: { enabled: false },
        poster: "<%=ImageSelector%>"
    }

    var azurePlayer = amp('<%=mediaPlayerID%>', playOptions);
    azurePlayer.src([{
        src: "<%=VideoURL%>",
        type: 'application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml'
    }]);

    azurePlayer.addEventListener("error", function () {
        var errorDetails = azurePlayer.error();
        var code = errorDetails.code;
        var message = errorDetails.message;
        alert(errorDetails + ' ' + code + " " + message);
        if (azurePlayer.error().code & amp.errorCode.abortedErrStart) {
            console.log("abortedErrStart");
        }
        else if (azurePlayer.error().code & amp.errorCode.networkErrStart) {
            // MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK errors
            console.log("networkErrStart");
        }
        else if (azurePlayer.error().code & amp.errorCode.decodeErrStart) {
            // MEDIA_ERR_DECODE errors
            console.log("decodeErrStart");
        }
        else if (azurePlayer.error().code & amp.errorCode.srcErrStart) {
            // MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED errors
            console.log("srcErrStart");
        }
        else if (azurePlayer.error().code & amp.errorCode.encryptErrStart) {
            // MEDIA_ERR_ENCRYPTED errors
            console.log("encryptErrStart");
        }
        else if (azurePlayer.error().code & amp.errorCode.srcPlayerMismatchStart) {
            // SRC_PLAYER_MISMATCH errors
            console.log("srcPlayerMismatchStart");

        }
        else {
            // unknown errors
            console.log("unknown");
        }

    });

    azurePlayer.addEventListener('play', function () {
        console.log('play');
    });
    azurePlayer.addEventListener('pause', function () {
        console.log('pause');
    });
});
```

**Updated**
Noticed I am getting following error for IE < 11.

[image: The Error is for minified version of azure JS]

Also I disabled the flash in firefox and removed the silverlight from techOrder, then it should hit the error event listener, it is not hitting.

This is also important for me to handle the analytics for error.
Play and Pause event listener are working fine.

**Update 8/28/2015:**
Fixed the JS error, it is because of multiple call to cdn of azure mentioned in link above, moved the code in master page and load it only once, browser like chrome handles duplicity of code easily but not IE.

After all the research I am lost why it is not working.
So added the following JS that will check for Silverlight and Flash and gracefully handle the error and update our analytics as well.

```
function getBrowserInformation() {
 var ua = navigator.userAgent, tem, M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
    tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
    return { name: 'IE ', version: (tem[1] || '') };
}
if (M[1] === 'Chrome') {
    tem = ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
    if (tem != null) { return { name: 'Opera', version: tem[1] }; }
}
M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) { M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]); }
return {
    name: M[0],
    version: M[1]
};};

function checkForAzureErrors() {
 function isSilverlightInstalled() {
    var isSilverlightInstalled = false;

    try {
        //check on IE
        try {
            var slControl = new ActiveXObject('AgControl.AgControl');
            isSilverlightInstalled = true;
        }
        catch (e) {
            //either not installed or not IE. Check Firefox/Safari
            if (navigator.plugins["Silverlight Plug-In"]) {
                isSilverlightInstalled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    return isSilverlightInstalled;
}

function isFlashInstalled() {
    try {
        return Boolean(new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'));
    } catch (exception) {
        return ('undefined' != typeof navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash']);
    }
}

function addErrorMessage() {
    $($("#mediaPlayer.marginBlock").find('h3')).text('Media is not supported on this browser or device.');
    $($("#mediaPlayer.marginBlock").find('video')).css('display', 'none');
    $($("#mediaPlayer.marginBlock").find('p')).css('display', 'none');
    $('.azuremediaplayer').css('display', 'none');
    ga("send", "event", "Videos", "error",
                        getBrowserInformation().name + getBrowserInformation().version +
                        ": is silverlight Installed " + isSilverlightInstalled() +
                        " and is Flash Installed " + isFlashInstalled());
}

function checkBrowser() {
    if ((getBrowserInformation().name === 'MSIE' || getBrowserInformation().name === 'IE')) {
        if (getBrowserInformation().version < 11) {
            addErrorMessage();
        }
    } else if (getBrowserInformation().name === 'Firefox') {
        addErrorMessage();
    }
}

if ((getBrowserInformation().name === 'MSIE' || getBrowserInformation().name === 'IE')) {
    if (getBrowserInformation().version < 9) { addErrorMessage() }
}

for (var key in amp.players) {
    if (amp.players.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (isSilverlightInstalled()) {
            if (!amp.players[key].isReady_) {
                checkBrowser();
            }
        } else if (!isFlashInstalled()) {
            checkBrowser();
        }
    }
}}
```

This function is called after 5 second of page load in document.ready function, giving it enough time to load and make the isReady_boolean true.

```
 SetTimeout(function () { checkForAzureErrors(); }, 5000);
```

Still I am waiting for some angel to resolve this issue.

**Updates: Partially Fixed**

Need to add the xap refrences like older version, it will play silverlight but there is a catch, it will only work if you have one video per page.

```
<script>
        amp.options.flashSS.swf = "http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/techs/StrobeMediaPlayback.2.0.swf"
        amp.options.flashSS.plugin = "http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/techs/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-osmf2.0.swf"
        amp.options.silverlightSS.xap = "http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/techs/SmoothStreamingPlayer.xap"
</script>
```

---

#### Fixed

As per comments from [Amit Rajput](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4734945/amit-rajput)

> @Parshii Currently, as per the documentation, Azure Media Player doesn't support multi-instance playback. While it may work on some techs, it is not a tested scenario at this time. Please feel free to add it to the UserVoice forum (http://aka.ms/ampuservoice).

As per my testing it is working in html5 and flash but not Silverlight, for silverlight support we can try using iframes as per comments from [rnrneverdies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573335/rnrneverdies)

Single Instance Media Player is working in all techs.

Comment: are you able to play the following with Silverlight: http://aka.ms/azuremediaplayer?url=%2F%2Famssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2F91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2%2FAzureMediaServicesPromo.ism%2Fmanifest&tech=Silverlight

Comment: @AmitRajput I am able to play with Silverlight but after giving references to.xap files as mentioned in comment to below answer, also the multiple videos are not playing, only the last one in dom will play all others will simply keep on showing the spinner. The control is partially fixed. The aka.ms link is able to play with silverlight.

Comment: Currently, as per the documentation, Azure Media Player doesn't support multi-instance playback. While it may work on some techs, it is not a tested scenario at this time. Please feel free to add it to the UserVoice forum (http://aka.ms/ampuservoice).

Answer (score 3):

@Parshii Currently, as per the documentation, Azure Media Player doesn't support multi-instance playback.  While it may work on some techs, it is not a tested scenario at this time.  Please feel free to add it to the UserVoice forum (http://aka.ms/ampuservoice).

Comment: nice suggestion @rnrneverdies, will try that, seeing the limitation of cms I am using this can be a tiring task.

Answer (score 2):

This may be not a complete answer, but could help you.

I made the following plugin for the Azure Media Player 1.3.0 which logs all the activity performed by the user and also the errors.

#### Set up it as:

```
var mylogFunction = function(data) { console.log(data); };
var options = {
        techOrder: ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "silverlightSS", "html5"],
        nativeControlsForTouch: false,
        loop: false,
        logo: { enabled: false },
        heuristicProfile: "Quick Start", //"High Quality", // could be "Quick Start"
        customPlayerSettings: {
            customHeuristicSettings: {
                preRollInSec: 4,
                windowSizeHeuristics: true
            }
        },
        plugins: {
          DebugLog: {
              logFunction: mylogFunction
          }
        }
      }; 

var amPlayer = amp("yourvideotagid", options);
```

#### Plugin Code:

```
var amp;
(function (amp) {

    amp.plugin('DebugLog', DebugLog);

    function DebugLog(options) {
        var player = this;

        var log = function (data) { console.log("Azure Media Player Log", data); }

        if (options) {            
            if (options['logFunction']) {
                log = options['logFunction'];
            }
        }

        init();

        function init() {
            player.ready(handleReady);
            player.addEventListener(amp.eventName.error, handleError);
        }

        function handleReady() {

            player.addEventListener(amp.eventName.loadedmetadata, handleLoadedMetaData);

            var data = {
                ampVersion: "1.3.0",
                appName: options['appName'],
                userAgent: navigator.userAgent,
                options: {
                    autoplay: player.options().autoplay,
                    heuristicProfile: player.options().heuristicProfile,
                    techOrder: JSON.stringify(player.options().techOrder)
                }
            };

            logData("InstanceCreated", 1, data);
        }

        function handleError() {
            var err = player.error();
            var data = {
                sessionId: player.currentSrc(),
                currentTime: player.currentTime(),
                code: "0x" + err.code.toString(16),
                message: err.message
            };

            logData("Error", 0, data);
        }

        function handleLoadedMetaData() {
            player.addEventListener(amp.eventName.playbackbitratechanged, handlePlaybackBitrateChanged);
            player.addEventListener(amp.eventName.playing, handlePlaying);
            player.addEventListener(amp.eventName.seeking, handleSeeking);
            player.addEventListener(amp.eventName.pause, handlePaused);
            player.addEventListener(amp.eventName.waiting, handleWaiting);
            player.addEventListener(amp.eventName.ended, handleEnded);

            if (player.audioBufferData()) {
                player.audioBufferData().addEventListener(amp.bufferDataEventName.downloadfailed, function () {

                    var data = {
                        sessionId: player.currentSrc(),
                        currentTime: player.currentTime(),
                        bufferLevel: player.audioBufferData().bufferLevel,
                        url: player.audioBufferData().downloadFailed.mediaDownload.url,
                        code: "0x" + player.audioBufferData().downloadFailed.code.toString(16),
                        message: player.audioBufferData().downloadFailed
                    };

                    logData("DownloadFailed", 0, data);
                });
            }

            if (player.videoBufferData()) {
                player.videoBufferData().addEventListener(amp.bufferDataEventName.downloadfailed, function () {

                    var data = {
                        sessionId: player.currentSrc(),
                        currentTime: player.currentTime(),
                        bufferLevel: player.videoBufferData().bufferLevel,
                        url: player.videoBufferData().downloadFailed.mediaDownload.url,
                        code: "0x" + player.videoBufferData().downloadFailed.code.toString(16),
                        message: player.videoBufferData().downloadFailed
                    };

                    logData("DownloadFailed", 0, data);
                });
            }

            var data = {
                sessionId: player.currentSrc(),
                isLive: player.isLive(),
                duration: player.duration(),
                tech: player.currentTechName(),
                protection: ((player.currentProtectionInfo() && player.currentProtectionInfo()[0]) ? player.currentProtectionInfo()[0].type : "clear")
            };

            logData("PresentationInfo", 1, data);
        }

        function handlePlaybackBitrateChanged(event) {
            logData("BitrateChanged", 1, eventData(event));
        }

        function handleWaiting(event) {
            logData("Waiting", 0, eventData(event));
        }

        function handlePlaying(event) {
            logData("Playing", 1, eventData(event));
        }

        function handleSeeking(event) {
            logData("Seeking", 1, eventData(event));
        }

        function handlePaused(event) {
            logData("Paused", 1, eventData(event));
        }

        function handleEnded(event) {
            logData("Ended", 1, eventData(event));
        }

        function logData(eventId, level, data) {

            var eventLog = {
                eventId: eventId,
                level: level,
                data: data
            };

            log(eventLog);
        }

        function eventData(event) {
          return {
              sessionId: player.currentSrc(),
              currentTime: player.currentTime(),
              isLive: player.isLive(),
              event: event.type,
              presentationTimeInSec: event.presentationTimeInSec,
              message: event.message ? event.message : ""
          };
        }
    }
})(amp || (amp = {}));
```

Comment: thanks, I have set up your code but I am not sure what is mylogFunction above.

Comment: Fixed it, Thanks I am getting all the events in log, your code is really good, but I am still not able to play in Silverlight and logging is also not happening, can it be a issue with CMS, as I am using sitefinity and telerik has lots of customized JS in browser running.

Comment: @Parshii i fixed the mylogFunction issue.

Comment: @rnrneverdies what is the "flash" in the tech order?  AMP only has "flashSS". Great plugin though!

Comment: Hi, I found a solution, even though version 1.3.0 doesn't need external references for .xap, I need to add those, I mean its a little weird but it worked for me. like this

<script>amp.options.flashSS.swf = http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/techs/StrobeMediaPlayback.2.0.swf"
amp.options.flashSS.plugin = "http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/techs/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-osmf2.0.swf"

   amp.options.silverlightSS.xap = "http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/techs/SmoothStreamingPlayer.xap"

  </script>

Comment: @AmitRajput i take it form the aka.ms/azuremediaplayer intialization code.

Comment: @Parshii that's the correct answer. My initialization code has these lines too

Comment: But my page has multiple videos, and it will play the last video only but not the other ones... I will update my question in few mins. Thanks @rnrneverdies

Comment: @rnrneverdies it might be left over legacy stuff but the tech "flash" is not required nor is it ever used. I will update the initialization code on that site.